# Exporting an array to CSV

Tags: csv, drupal-7

I need a module for Drupal 7 that can export CSV when given an array of values.

Comment: instead of writing a comment you could simply flag the post as `not a real question`. :)

Answer (score 12):

Sorry for the late response but I just ran across this while searching for my own solution. This is what I ended up with:

```
// send response headers to the browser
drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
drupal_add_http_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=csvfile.csv');

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach($csv_array as $line){
  fputcsv($fp, $line);
}
fclose($fp);
drupal_exit();
```

That should be in a page callback and it will result in a file download of a csv file with the array contents. Hope this helps.

Comment: Here is the full code, use this, and add a <a> with the href to your callback. http://drupalpeople.com/blog/output-data-csv-file-drupal-download

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Drupal for this, you can use the PHP [fputcsv function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php). Have a look at that page, there are clear examples of how to save an array as a CSV file.

Hope that helps

Comment: I need to create a module especially for Drupal 7 which takes array and export to csv file